# Download compiled html file using angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs, compilation

So for this project, I'd like to save the compiled html after its dynamically altered using ng-bind. The file downloads however, the result is uncompiled. To some it up, I'm using $(element).html to get that code, its probably something simple that I'm missing.

Any ideas on how to get the compiled result as an object in angular.js? Here's part of the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
var data = $('div#testing').html;
$scope.getBlob = function(){
  return new Blob([data], {type: 'text/html'});
};
});
```

The function to download that html:

```
app.directive('myDownload', function($compile)  {
 return {
restrict:'E',
replace: true,
scope:{ getUrlData:'&getData'},
link:function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(scope.getUrlData());
      elm.append($compile(
            '<a class="btn" download="Email.html"' +
                'href="' + url + '">' +
                'Download' +
                '</a>'
        )(scope));
    }
};
});
```